# Strip transformations from formula

Tags: r, formula

I have a model formula that includes transformations, some of which can be nested. I want to strip all transformations from the formula, leaving just the raw variables.

E.g.,

```
log10(y) ~ sin(log10(x)) + log(x1)
```

would become:

```
y ~ x + x1
```

I imagine this could be done with regular expressions, but I want to know if there is a pre-existing function or if the raw variable names are stored somewhere (e.g., `terms`), from which the formula could be reconstructed. If not, then perhaps someone can help with the regex in cases with nesting...?

Unfortunately, it is not an option to transform the variables outside of the formula.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function, `all.vars`, for extracting the variables from formulas

```
all.vars( log10(y) ~ sin(log10(x)) + log(x1) )
# [1] "y"  "x"  "x1"
```

Comment: If `v` is the result of `all.vars(...)` then use: `formula(paste(v[1], "~", paste(v[-1], collapse = " + ")))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck or `reformulate(v[1],v[-1])` (does the same thing but I think it's more clear what the intention is)

Comment: Will `all.vars` return in the same order as the model formula? If so, perfect solution! Can't believe I didn't think of it!

Comment: You can also look at `lapply(attr(terms(f,keep.order=TRUE),'variables'),all.vars)`